# Joomla 3.5.1 Search function not working on index page

Tags: search, joomla

Recently updated Joomla site using 3.5.1 and now the search function on the home page does nothing.  All that happens when you enter a search term into the box is the page refreshes.  All other pages, when you use the search function, results pop up as normal.  I have tried googling but only see this issue years back... any help would be so appreciated..

Comment: Please consider editing your question to be [a Complete, Minimal, Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

In your index page there may be some modules with JQuery conflict. You can check by disabling third party modules that are active on index page. You can also get the exact error if you check console log while loading that page.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
In modules/mod_search/tmpl/default.php
I changed line 29 from 
`<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php');?>" method="post" class="form-inline">` 
to 
`<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('/');?>" method="post" class="form-inline">`

and now search works everywhere.